# Is there an effective way to export Test Coverage result

Tags: unit-test, reporting

Although this idea has been talked in Salesforce success community for a long time, currently there is still no Salesforce supported way to export Test coverage report. So is there any third party tool which can effectively retrieve Test coverage report without having to install the app into Salesforce org?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a opensource tool to retrieve the test coverage report by using node js and jsforce. The github link is: https://github.com/Lanceshi2/GetSFTestCoverage

It generates the test report in both .csv and .html form. The generated html looks like this:

[image]

The advantages are:

1. You don't need to install anything into your salesforce org so you can keep your org clean.
2. No OAuth2 app creation in Salesforce org is needed.
3. The web service is running on localhost. So there is no security issue.

Answer (score 2):

What data do you want? I made a Code Coverage tab in the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) that lists the coverage details for each class.

[image]

You can copy and paste the report data out.

Otherwise you can use the APIs to pull the same data directly.

Comment: This tools looks very handy!